# jQuery Ajax Checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html

The taskid attribute in the JavaScript code is always "2", but need it to be 1, 2, 3 etc. What is wrong?

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="taskstat" name="check" taskid="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="taskstat" name="check" taskid="1">
```

and JavaScript:

```
$(".todo-list").todolist({
    onCheck: function(ele) {
         var id = $(".taskstat").attr('taskid');
         $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"task_change.php",
            data: "check="+id,
         });
    },
    onUncheck: function(ele) {
         var id = $(".taskstat").attr('taskid');
         $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"task_change.php",
            data: "uncheck="+id,
         });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, Hope it helps!

```js
$(".taskstat").on('change', function(){
    var selectedTaskID = $(this).data('taskid');
  
    $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"task_change.php",
            data: "uncheck="+selectedTaskID,
    });
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="taskstat" name="check" data-taskid="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="taskstat" name="check" data-taskid="1">
```

Comment: The TaskID will always "1", but I won't so. The ID must take over of input "taskid".